# C# providing C++ callbacks, Access violation in _threadex.c in the endthread ()

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a C# Windows service application that passes a callback function pointer to a C++ dll. I have defined both the function pointer at the C# side and C++ side to be __stdcall type. Everything works fine till the callback is triggered by the C++ dll and throws an Unhandled Exception Access Violation in 0x04cb0e. The debug stops in the threadex.c under the endthread call in the C# application.

```
public delegate void NotificationFunc(int notifycode, IntPtr Userdata);

[DllImport("notice.dll")]
void INotify(NotificationFunc notefunc,IntPtr Userdata);//ignore the IntPtr Userdata
.
.
.
NotificationFunc notefunc = new NotificationFunc(Noticallback);
INotify(notefunc, Intptr.zero);

//notice.dll triggers this callback thru the delegate passed in
void Noticallback(int notifycode, IntPtr userdata)
{
Swtich(notifycode)
{
//my actions
}
.
.//Error Exceptions happens here when trying to end the thread/call
}
```

I know i have to handle the clean up this callback resources as it is a one way call event. I have tried GC & GCHandle to prevent it from being GC but it seems there is always a memory leak or error.Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Are you storing the callback in a local variable? The GC is free to collect local variables as soon as it reaches a point where the code no longer appears to reference it, so it's possible that your delegate is being collected earlier than it appears to be.

Also, can you include the code from the C++ call site so we can see how it's being invoked and what the C++ signature is?

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) has a fairly decent article on the topic.  If I were you, I would use C++/CLI as it's faster and not so strongly bound.  This sort of P/Invoke, where you layout all the definitions all over the place, is so error prone.  And if you ever change, or if the spec changes on you, for your data types or something like that, C++/CLI will automatically be updated, but unfortunately any explicit P/Invoke's declerations as you have here, will always have to be re-wired.

Answer (score 1):

You must prevent the delegate from being collected by the managed code, using `GCHandle.Alloc`:

```
    public delegate void NotificationFunc(int notifycode, IntPtr Userdata);

    [DllImport("notice.dll")]
    static extern void INotify(NotificationFunc notefunc,IntPtr Userdata); // Note IntPtr as the callback type


    NotificationFunc notefunc = new NotificationFunc(Noticallback);

    // Now, allocate a GCHandle to prevent the delegate from being collected
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(notefunc);

    INotify(notefunc, Intptr.Zero);

    // Free the handle when it's no longer needed
    handle.Free();
```